# PowerShell - "Click" an HTML input element with type "submit"

Tags: javascript, html, powershell, automation

I'm looking at a webpage with an input of type "submit":

```
<input name="loginForm:j_idt56:loginButton" id="loginForm:j_idt56:loginButton" onclick="this.style.display='none'; document.getElementById('euLoginButDis').style.display='inline';" type="submit" value="Login">
```

I would like to use PowerShell to "click" this input.  My script looks like:

```
$username = "USERNAME" 
$password = "PASSWORD"

$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 

$ie.visible=$true

$ie.navigate("URL") 

while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100} 

$ie.document.getElementById("loginForm:j_idt21:username:username").value= "$username" 
$ie.document.getElementById("loginForm:j_idt42:password:passwordb").value = "$password" 
# $ie.document.getElementById("loginForm:j_idt56:loginButton").submit()

start-sleep 20 

# $ie.Document.body | Out-File -FilePath c:\web.txt
```

I'm using code from another user on StackOverflow, who I assume was interacting with a button input.  But this is a "submit".  I've tried the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721295/powershell-how-to-click-a-submit-type-input), but get the errors:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:16 char:36
+ $commit = $doc.getElementsByTagName <<<< ("input")
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (getElementsByTagName:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

and

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:16 char:36
+ $commit = $doc.getElementsByTagName <<<< ("input") | ? { $_.name -eq "commit" }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (getElementsByTagName:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "click" with "0" argument(s): "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))"
At line:17 char:29
+ if ($commit) { $commit.click <<<< () }
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodCOMException
```

respectively.

How can I click this button?

Comment: Any reason you prefer powershell for automation over a webdriver-based tool?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with webdriver-based tools.  I had started thinking about doing this with AutoIt, but then realized I could do it with PowerShell.  And since there are a lot of other potential uses for PowerShell in my work, I thought it would be a good learning exercise.  What are the benefits of webdriver-based tools?

Comment: Lots of benefits: OS-independent, open-source, multi-language support, vibrant user communities.  The most popular one is selenium-webdriver, so you might want to check that out.