# Navigate a website through Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I've looked into multiple threads about this, logging into a website etc. But none of the solutions seemed to work for me and the site I'm using specifically.
Backstory: I'm trying to sell my CS:GO skins for the best price on OPSKINS.

My goal is to make a program that changes the price 1 dollar less for every day it's not sold.

What I have so far is:

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application

$ie.visible=$true

$ie.Navigate("https://opskins.com")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
```

This work's fine and opens the page, exactly how I want it, with me already signed in.

Then in the manage sales page it's supposed to click the Manage button.
Which is where I'm having difficulty.

```
<button class="btn btn-default">Manage</button>
```

Is what the Manage button shows as in Inspect Element, but no matter what I try I cannot get it to click it.

I've tried looking into all the other posts about clicking the button but nothing works.

Comment: You should try [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/), you can address your button by the class name.

Comment: You can use the `GetElementbyID` or the `GetElementsbyName` property of the the button and then click it using the `click()` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [powershell: how to click a "submit type" input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721295/powershell-how-to-click-a-submit-type-input)